# sort item in the list in customised way

Tags: c#, list

I have list which i want to loop through and sort it on fixed name. If say my list has items as,

```
List[0] = "Banana";
List[1] = "Orange";
List[2] = "Apple";
List[3] = "Olive";
```

Then i want to have orange always at the top. 
So my order will be **Orange=>Banana=>Mango=>Olive.**

I just dont know how do i sort it in customised way.

I tried using

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Name).toList();
```

but this gives Olive oil at the top. 
What could be way to sort this? Any suggestions?

**Update**
If Orange is not present in list then i dont need any sorting.

Comment: [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) `Orange` from the list, if it was present sort the list, [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) `Orange` as the first element.

Comment: You can make an Enum (placing items in the order that you want your items to be sorted) and then use the same LINQ query that you shared here (by casting each enum item to int).. So your list would be a List<CustomSortEnum>

Comment: @millimoose can you show how?

Comment: @Happy ...Seriously? This is collections operations 101. I even linked to the methods.

Comment: As an aside, you might want to make your code sample and description a little consistent. In the code you have "apple" then in the next line it's "mango", and later on it's "olive oil" instead of "olive". You're also showing us a list of strings but then you sort on some `Name` property.

Comment: And can you clarify that you just want "Orange" at the front, if present? You don't need to sort the other items at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.Name != "Orange").ToList();
```

That will move "Orange" items to the top of list, because key selector will have value `false` for these items. And for other items it will be `true`.

---

Same for your strings sample:

```
List.OrderBy(x => x != "Orange")
```

Gives

```
Orange // false
Banana // true
Apple  // true
Olive  // true
```

Comment: So "Banana" comes before "Apple"? Hmmm.

Comment: @MatthewWatson why would it come after? It comes first in source collection. Requirement is only to have "Orange" items on top.

Comment: He says he wants to `sort it on fixed name`, which I perhaps misunderstood to mean that he wanted to sort it. I guess he just meant that if the list contains "Orange" it should be placed at the front.

Comment: Isn't `OrderBy` a little overkill just to move an element to the front of a list? Like, replacing an O(n) operation with O(n log n)?

Comment: @millimoose it is simple and will work if there several elements with "Orange". Performance? Never optimize it before you have problems. It could be executed twice a week on four items list. Who knows

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Good point with the multiple occurences, that makes it a little more warranted. (You can still do this simply enough with a `RemoveAll()` assuming the objects are value objects though, I'll leave that in my answer as an alternative. If the "oranges" aren't interchangeable this answer is much simpler while remaining reliable.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input list is a list of `string`s, the following will place all "Orange"s at the start:

```
var fruits = new List<string> {
    "Banana",
    "Orange",
    "Apple",
    "Olive"
};

const string Orange = "Orange";

for (int i = 0; i < fruits.RemoveAll(fr => fr == Orange); i++) {
    fruits.Insert(0, Orange);
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", fruits));
```

This requires the `Orange`s to be interchangeable value / valuelike objects.

Comment: Since we now know that sorting isn't required, your answer simplifies to `if (list.Remove("Orange")) list.Insert(0, "Orange");` (and is then the best answer IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `enum` for fruits and assign the values to `enums` depending upon your customization.

```
public enum Fruits
{
    Orange = 1,
    Banana = 2,
    Mango = 3,
    Olive = 4
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Fruits[] List = new Fruits[4];
    List[0] = Fruits.Banana;
    List[1] = Fruits.Orange;
    List[2] = Fruits.Mango;
    List[3] = Fruits.Olive;

    var sortedList = List.OrderBy(x => x);

    foreach (var item in sortedList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your list, check if it contains "Orange", if it does remove the item (not based on `Index` so that it could be anywhere in the list) then insert "Orange" again at the start of the list.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("Banana");
myList.Add("Orange");
myList.Add("Apple");
myList.Add("Olive");

if (myList.Contains("Orange"))
{
    myList.Remove("Orange");
    myList.Insert(0,"Orange");
}
```

Assuming your "Orange" is an object with properties you would want to alter the above to create a new single intance of that object type, with all the same properties as the original (effectively `object` = `object`).